# How to schedule a job to run every 10 minutes in TWS

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, scheduler, tivoli

TWS is Tivoli Workload Scheduler.

I have scheduled a job, and made it repeatable every 10 minutes. I put it in a job stream with a run cycle of daily.

Now, the job runs once every ten minutes on the first day, twice on the second day and so on.

What is the correct way to schedule a job in TWS to run many times every day?

Is there anything wrong with this job definition:

```
Workstation       Job Stream Name   Valid From  Updated On  Locked By
----------------  ----------------  ----------  ----------  ----------------
VMWSOAAPP01-TST   PDSSITRNS_INTG_H  -           01/17/2012  -

SCHEDULE MACHINE01-TST#JOBSTREAM
DESCRIPTION "SomeTransfer.sh  param1"
ON RUNCYCLE RC1 DESCRIPTION "Daily every hour" "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
KEYSCHED
:
MACHINE01-TST#JOBNAME
 SCRIPTNAME "/shared/app/app2/fds/bin/TWS/SomeTransfer.sh  param1"

 STREAMLOGON auser
 TASKTYPE UNIX
 RECOVERY STOP
 AT 0645 UNTIL 0545 +1 DAYS
 EVERY 0010
 KEYJOB
END
```

Comment: looks like you have a carryforward issue: this schedule seems not to be carryforwarded but you see jobs pilling up? what is the output of `optman ls | grep carryforward` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use TWS/d,

- you add your job into a jobstream.
- right click at the job
- select properties
- select time restrictions
- select repeat range ( from hh:mm to hh:mm and how often )

Then you also have to define which days in week / month / year the job shoudl run

- click at the "run cycle" icon
- click at the "add run cycle" icon
- select which days the job should run

Save job stream

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need. This worked for me:

```
#Start at 6am, every 5 minutes, don't run after 5am tomorrow
#But make sure you don't start the next instance of this job
#before the previous instance finishes.  In case the job might
#take 10 minutes to run some time, and I don't want the next
#instance to start before the previous one ends..

SCHEDULE XLDETL01#EITST_EVERY_J
 DESCRIPTION "Schedule a job every 5 minutes, but job takes 10 minutes"
 ON RUNCYCLE DAILY "FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1"
 CARRYFORWARD
 MATCHING PREVIOUS
 FOLLOWS XLDETL01#EITST_EVERY_J.@
:
XLDETL01#DMEITST_TSTG0001_DUMMY_10
  AT 0600 EVERY 0005 UNTIL 0500 ONUNTIL CANC
  FOLLOWS XLDETL01#EITST_EVERY_J.DMEITST_TSTG0001_DUMMY_10 PREVIOUS
END
```